# Finding posterior density of discrete distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Consider a process in which someone is asked to do a task and iff they succeed, they are allowed to repeat the task. Let $X$ be the number of times the task is successfully completed and suppose that different attempts at the task are iid and the probability of success on any one attempt is $0 \le \theta \le 1$.

$$
\displaystyle P(X=x) =
\begin{cases}
1-\theta & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\theta(1-\theta) & \text{if } x = 1 \\
\theta^2 & \text{if } x = 2 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Suppose in addition that we observe $X=1$ and that the prior density for $\theta$ is $\text{Unif}[0,1]$. The first task is to find the posterior density for $\theta$.

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle f(\theta;{\bf x}) &= \frac{f({\bf x}; \theta)f(\theta)}{C} 
\end{align*}

where $c$ is a constant independent of $\theta$. How does one proceed from here? I think we can drop $f(\theta)$ from the numerator since it is constant $1$. Is $f({\bf x}; \theta) = P(X=x)?$, so in this case, since we have observed $X=1$, is $f({\bf x}; \theta) =\theta(1-\theta)$? Working as outlined above I find $C=6$. Let me know if this outline has an flaws.

What seems harder to me is the following: what is the posterior probability that the next time this person goes through the process the $\#$ of observed successes will be $2$? How does one translate this last question into probability? That is, are we looking for $f(\theta; X=2)$? I don't think so. So what exactly do we want to calculate here?

Any comments or suggestions are, as always, deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posterior distribution is indeed the Beta(2,2) distribution when $X=1$. Which is associated with $C=1/6$, rather than $C=6$. Regarding your second question, you are looking at a future value for which the Bayesian answer is the posterior predictive, that is the distribution of $X'$ conditional on $X$, which writes as
$$\mathbb{P}(X'=x|X=1) = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}_\theta(X'=x) f(\theta|X=1)\text{d}\theta$$
So, for instance,$$\mathbb{P}(X'=2|X=1) = \int_0^1 \theta^2 f(\theta|X=1)\text{d}\theta=\int_0^1 \theta^2 6\theta(1-\theta)\text{d}\theta=\frac{6}{20}$$